# When moving a directory to another file system, and it runs out of space, are files removed?

Tags: rm, mv

Given `/mnt/source/` and `/mnt/target/` which are two different places / filesystems.

- `mv  /mnt/source/dir  /mnt/target/`
- It runs out of space part-way (and stops)

---

1. Imagining that `/mnt/source/dir` is full of directories, sub-directories and files, when the `mv` fails, are any files removed from `/mnt/source/dir` ?
2. Can I safely delete my failure ( `rm /mnt/target/dir` ), prepare more space on the `/mnt/target/` file system, and try the move operation again?
3. Or perhaps:  If I am unable to prepare more space on the `/mnt/target/` file system, should I do some sort of "undo" like `mv /mnt/target/dir/* /mnt/source/dir/` (with a file manager, to overwrite target files) so I can change my mind and not attempt the move at all?

---

related:
  [What happens when you force quit a `mv` directory operation between two disks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509992/)

Answer (score 1):

> Are files removed from /mnt/source/foo ?

Not until the command reports a succes on moving.

```
$ $ mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

and

```
$ info mv
```

has information on what happens:

> `mv`can move any type of file from one file system to another.
>   Prior to version 4.0 of the fileutils, `mv` could move only regular
>   files between file systems.  For example, now `mv` can move an entire
>   directory hierarchy including special device files from one partition to
>   another. **It first uses some of the same code that's used by `cp -a` to
>   copy the requested directories and files, then (assuming the copy
>   succeeded) it removes the originals**.  If the copy fails, then the part
>   that was copied to the destination partition is removed.  **If you were to
>   copy three directories from one partition to another and the copy of the
>   first directory succeeded, but the second didn't, the first would be
>   left on the destination partition and the second and third would be left
>   on the original partition.**

Mind the 2nd part in bold: it is done on each `mv` you do so

```
mv a b c /dir/
```

will remove "a" in between "a" and "b".

Comment: So that means YES some files can be removed from /mnt/source/foo and NO I cannot safely delete /mnt/dest/bar?

Comment: No. It depends on the "mv". "mv  /mnt/source/foo  /mnt/dest/bar/" if "foo" is 1 file or a directory the deleting will take place after foo is moved. ONLY if you move more files and/or directories in 1 go you need to watch out (so "mv a b c /bar/")

Comment: I think I'm understanding better.  I clarified my question:  It is not 1 file, it is many directories, sub-directories and files within the source.  The second part of `info mv` seems to say I must not delete my `/mnt/target/`.  ---  It also seems like file managers (in my case spacefm and midnight commander) do not necessarily operate the same way.  Maybe they are copying first, and only remove any source files if the operation succeeds?